# how to loop through a list of object to find total value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of objects and I need to loop through each object add all the "price" field to get the total value.

```
[
{
"_id":"61d167f9f5986df9dd291603",
"name":"test2",
"price":2000
},
{
"_id":"61d167f9f5986df9dd291602",
"name":"test3",
"price":4000
},
{
"_id":"61d167f9f5986df9dd291601",
"name":"test4",
"price":5000
}
]
```

I tried doing,

```
for(i in items){
let total = total + i.price;
}
console.log(total)
```

But dint work.

Comment: Your `total` is scoped to your inner loop.  Move it's defination outside.

Comment: If you log `i` what information does that give you?

Comment: _Didn't work_ is not very helpful. May be more helpful to be more descriptive.
Change the keyword `in` to `of` and declare `total` before the loop.

Comment: Oh, and just noticed you maybe wanted `of` and not `in`

Comment: This is an excellent example of when to use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```js
const items = [{"_id":"61d167f9f5986df9dd291603","name":"test2","price":2000},{"_id":"61d167f9f5986df9dd291602","name":"test3","price":4000},{"_id":"61d167f9f5986df9dd291601","name":"test4","price":5000}];

let total = 0;
for(let i = 0; i <= items.length - 1; i++) {
    total += items[i].price
}
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Worth noting your `for (i = 0;`,   `i` is now a global var, you maybe meant to do `for (let i = 0;`...

Comment: @Keith Yeah either works.

Comment: Indeed, but if you want a better chance of getting up-votes, it's usually better to provide better code.. :)  Just saying,..

Comment: @Keith That logic does check out.

Answer (score -1):

Fetch this JSOn data into the List / ArrayList and using the for each loop traverse that list using object.
Example -
Suppose your data is stored in list whose object name is data
int total = 0
for each list_data_type  in data1
total = data1.price + total;